# SQL Server: How to Determine all tables associated with replication, and which articles

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

How would I iterate through the tables of a database, and determine which publication and article those tables are associated with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of profiling, and I found this, which I then looked at to find the parameters:
[sys].[sp_MShelp_replication_table] (
    @table_name sysname = NULL,
    @table_owner sysname = NULL
    )

Answer (score 1):

You will have a database that is normally called `DISTRIBUTION` that houses your tables. Note: This name can be changed at the time replication is configured.

The following tables will give you information about the replication:

- `MSPublications`
- `MSArticles`

You can join these tables to the `Information_Schema.Tables` in your database and figure out which tables are a part of what publication.

Comment: Okay... that's coming at it from the other side, which will totally work. I was hoping that maybe there was a SQL Server proc that, given a table name, would indicate the publication and article it was associated with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this system table:
     `SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmergearticles`

Comment: Actually, not quite enough, here's the best Ad-hoc: `SELECT s.[name] AS [Publication name] FROM dbo.sysmergepublications AS s 
INNER JOIN dbo.sysmergearticles AS s2 ON s.pubid = s2.pubid 
WHERE s2.NAME = 'MyTable'`